# How to disable Mac hotkeys in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook-pro, hotkeys

I've installed Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro and want to turn off the Mac hotkeys. I don't like them, especially F1-F12, and want to turn them off but can't find this option anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you installed the Boot Camp software including keyboard driver.

Open `Control Panel`, then `Boot Camp Control Panel` (you could also search for Boot Camp in start menu and I think there's some icon in the system tray next to the clock). Click on tab `Keyboard` and check `Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys`.

It's quite some time ago I used boot camp, not sure if the way to get there is still valid, but this option will be somewhere in the Boot Camp Settings. If I've been wrong please add a new answer or tell me the new way to get there!